# How do I replace a letter and a digit inside a square bracket with just the same digit and the letter outside the bracket in sed?

Tags: linux, string, bash, replace, sed

How would I do this for example:

```
replace: today_is_sunny[0F]
with: today_is_sunny_F[0]
```

keeping in mind that the zero inside the square bracket can be any digit and the letter inside the square bracket is always F.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking any digit into consideration:

```
sed -e 's;\(\[\)\([0-9]\)F;_F\1\2;'
```

Usage might be:

```
echo 'today_is_sunny[0F]' | sed -e 's;\(\[\)\([0-9]\)F;_F\1\2;'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do the trick

```
sed 's|today_is_sunny\[\([0-9]\)F\]|today_is_sunny_F\[\1\]|'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
echo "today_is_sunny[0F]" | sed 's/\[\([0-9]\)F\]/_F\[\1\]/g'
```

Answer (score 0):

this short line should solve your problem:

```
sed 's/\[/_F&/;s/.]/]/' file
```

e.g.

```
kent$  echo "today_is_sunny[0F]"|sed 's/\[/_F&/;s/.]/]/'
today_is_sunny_F[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

An example using named character classes:

```
sed -r 's/\[([[:digit:]])([[:alpha:]])\]/\2[\1]/'
```